# Trouble building PySide on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

I am trying build PySide on a Mac running El Capitan (10.11.5).

This is the command I am using:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --cmake=/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake
```

However, every time I run this, I get the following error messages:

```
In file included from /Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:38:
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.h:56:76: error: virtual function
      'metaObject' has a different return type ('Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>') than the function it overrides (which has return type 'const QMetaObject *')
    virtual Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType > metaObject() const;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/phonon/objectdescriptionmodel.h:202:68: note: overridden virtual function is here
            PHONON_TEMPLATE_CLASS_MEMBER_EXPORT const QMetaObject *metaObject() const;
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/include/phonon/objectdescriptionmodel.h:194:40: error: base class 'QAbstractListModel' has private copy constructor
    class PHONON_TEMPLATE_CLASS_EXPORT ObjectDescriptionModel : public QAbstractListModel
                                       ^
/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qabstractitemmodel.h:380:20: note: declared private here
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QAbstractListModel)
                   ^
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:636:16: note: implicit copy
      constructor for 'Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::ObjectDescriptionType::AudioOutputDeviceType>' first required here
        return ::Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType >(((::QObject*)0));
               ^
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:641:16: error: no viable
      conversion from returned value of type 'const QMetaObject *' to function return type 'Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>'
        return this->::Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceModel::metaObject();
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:651:16: error: no matching
      constructor for initialization of 'Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>'
        return ::Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType >(((::QObject*)0));
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:656:150: error: no matching
      function for call to 'SbkType'
  ...2, "Invalid return value in function %s, expected %s, got %s.", "AudioOutputDeviceModel.metaObject", Shiboken::SbkType< Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel >()->tp_name, pyResult->ob_type->tp_n...
                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_install/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/include/shiboken/conversions.h:52:15: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
      argument for template parameter 'T'
PyTypeObject* SbkType()
              ^
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:657:16: error: no matching
      constructor for initialization of 'Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>'
        return ::Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType >(((::QObject*)0));
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:662:12: error: no viable
      conversion from returned value of type '::Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType> *' to function return type
      'Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>'
    return cppResult;
           ^~~~~~~~~
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp/PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp:1460:157: error: 
      incompatible operand types ('Phonon::ObjectDescriptionModel<Phonon::AudioOutputDeviceType>' and 'const QMetaObject *')
  ...? reinterpret_cast<AudioOutputDeviceModelWrapper*>(cppSelf)->::AudioOutputDeviceModelWrapper::metaObject() : cppSelf->metaObject());
     ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings and 8 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [PySide/phonon/CMakeFiles/phonon.dir/PySide/phonon/phonon_audiooutputdevicemodel_wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [PySide/phonon/CMakeFiles/phonon.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Error compiling pyside
```

What is especially maddening is that I have edited the phonon_audiooutputdevicemodelwrapper files, but the edits do not seem to stick.  Running the setup.py script seems to undo my changes.

I do not need the Phonon module.  However, I do not see a way to skip this module with the PySide build.  I can skip this with Qt, but I would prefer to not have to rebuild that again.

#### ADDITION 8/10/16

Strange, I rebuilt Qt without Phonon:

```
$ ./configure –no-phonon –no-phonon-backend
```

I still have that same issue.

Then I removed the phonon directory (PySide-1.2.4/pyside_build/py2.7-qt4.8.6-64bit-release/pyside/PySide/phonon) and got a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I built PySide without Phonon:

Download the PySide source to a temp direct and uncompress the archive:

```
$ pwd
/Users/spearsc/Documents/pyside_tmp
$ tar –xvzf  dist\PySide-1.2.4.tar
```

Now you need to edit PySide-1.2.4/sources/pyside/CMakeLists.txt.  Find this line (line 33 I believe):

```
HAS_QT_MODULE(QT_PHONON_FOUND phonon)
```

Just comment out that line:

```
# HAS_QT_MODULE(QT_PHONON_FOUND phonon)
```

Then run the setup.py script:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel --cmake=/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake
```